# SQL Reading from a DB problem using a DataReader

Tags: c#, sql, database, arraylist, sqldatareader

I have a table of Users (tblUsers) which contains details of University staff. I am trying to populate a text box with the names of lecturers associated with a selected module.

I am getting all UserIDs associated with a particular module, testing if the User is a lecturer, if so then I add the ID to an ArrayList.

I then iterate through this array and call the method below during each iteration passing through the current ID.

However, if you look at the method below I am using a SqlDataReader and am getting an error while reading from it on this line:

txtLecturerName.Text += myReader["First_Name"].ToString();

The error message is:
'myReader["First_Name"]' threw an exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'

The table layout I am using is below the method code. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, I am one cup of coffee away from putting my head through the screen.

```
public void outputLecturerNames(string lecturerID)
{
    // Create a new Connection object using the connection string
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(conStr);

    // If the connection is already open - close it
    if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }

    // 'using' block allows the database connection to be closed
    // first and then the exception handling code is triggered.
    // This is a better approach than using a 'finally' block which
    // would close the connection after the exception has been handled.
    using (myConnection)
    {
        try
        {
            // Open connection to DB
            myConnection.Open();

            SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, myConnection);

            // Declare a new DataReader
            SqlDataReader myReader;

            selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE User_ID='";
            selectQuery += lecturerID + "'";

            myReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                txtLecturerName.Text += myReader["First_Name"].ToString();
                txtLecturerName.Text += " ";
                txtLecturerName.Text += myReader["Last_Name"].ToString();
                txtLecturerName.Text += " , ";
            }
            myReader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + err);
        }
    }
}
```

tblUsers:

```
[User_ID][First_Name][Last_Name][Email_Address]
```

Comment: What is the structure of tblUsers?  The error says there is no column named: First_Name.

Comment: Hi Fosco, the column names are listed in the correct order below the method code. Thanks

Comment: on a side note - be very careful concatenating user input strings or better yet parametrize the query or use an ORM tool.

Comment: What happens if you remove the where clause from the SQL statement?  I'm wondering if something in the lecturerID is causing the SQL statement to be modified (SQL injection type stuff).  Also, what happens if you use an index of 0?  In your response to devio you said you tried with an index of 1.

Comment: THANK YOU EVERYONE! You are all great! If you look at the method you'll see that I foolishly declare my SqlCommand before assigning the selectQuery meaning that I was using the wrong select statements in my queries - hence the IndexOutOfRange exceptions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your method, the variable selectQuery is not declared, and it is used as parameter to SqlCommand before it is assigned the query string on tblUsers.

Comment: Hi devio, you are correct sorry for not saying it before but I have declared the string selectQuery outside of the method.

Comment: @Frank what is the contents of selectQUery at the time you assign it to SqlCommand? You set the tblUsers query statement after creating the command

Comment: HAHA!! I just discovered this by stepping thru line by line for the millionth time! My foolish mistake was declaring the SqlCommand before assigning the selectQuery. I was reading data from the wrong results. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You've probably misspelled a column name.

In general, you should never write `SELECT * FROM ...`.
Instead, you should select only the columns you need.

This will make your program run faster by only querying the information that you need, and can produce better error messages.

Comment: Thanks Slaks, I just want to get the code functional first of all and then I intend to make it more efficient - thanks for the suggestion. It doesnt appear to be a column name though...

Answer (score 0):

This error is created when the column name given is not found.  If you are anything like me, you've probably checked it several times, but is the table name correct (correct database, correct schema) and is the column name correct?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f01t4cfy.aspx

You might try fully qualifying the name of the table (database.dbo.tblUsers).  This would ensure that you are hitting the table you think you are.  Also, try and put the names of the columns into the SQL statement.  If they are not correct, your SQL statement will not execute properly.